# ¿Validar con unique mas de un campo en Lavaravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo que registrar clientes pero al momento de hacerlo, tengo que validar que el cliente no exista tomando en cuenta su nombre y la calle donde vive. Sé como validar por el nombre o la calle pero no usando los dos campos.

Validar que no exista nombre

```
'nombre'        =>  'unique:clientes,nombre|required'
```

Comment: lo haces igual y el modelo valida si se cumple uno de los 2 o los 2 y muestra los respectivos errores.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, de esa forma no lograría lo que quiero porque estaría siempre validando que esa calle no exista pero la calle si puede existir muchas veces, la condición que busco es que no exista ya un usuario con esa calle, ¿Me explico?

Comment: Intenta extender tu validación y crea tu propia regla